# Trying to shuffle rows in Panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hopefully, someone can help, I'm trying to randomize the output 15 times, and save into excel, however, python is only giving me 1 output instead of 15

```
import pandas as pd

# create a DataFrame
sales_to_do = {'Task': ['Call with the client', 'Preparing for the calls', 'Training staff',
                    'Daily tasks (Emails, questions, chasing)'],

           'Type of task': ['Call (external - new lead)', 'Preparing communication with 
leads', 'Training',
                            'Call (external - new lead)']}

df = pd.DataFrame(sales_to_do)
df_shuffled = df.sample(frac=1)

def randomize():
    df = pd.DataFrame(sales_to_do)
    df_shuffled = df.sample(frac=1)
    print(df_shuffled)


for i in range(15):
    randomize()

df_shuffled.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Output1.xlsx', index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: Should your last line be within the loop?  Right now you're just executing the `to_excel` once.  And if you fix that by tabbing it in, you'll be overwriting the same file repeatedly, so you may want to use an `fstring` to dynamically name the output file.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you, but how could I save it all in 1 excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this where you just return the shuffled df, and use `pd.concat` on a list of these.

```
sales_to_do = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2], 'name':['bob','mike']})

def randomize(df):
    return df.sample(frac=1)
    
df_shuffled = pd.concat([randomize(sales_to_do) for x in range(15)])

df_shuffled.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Output1.xlsx', index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: @AlexeyPodoynitsyn If you copy and paste this code, run it, you should see the desired output from the sample dataframe.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I copied your code and filled in my data and it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the scoping rules.  You have two independent variables named `df_shuffled`, one each in `randomize` and your main program.  You never link the two.  As a result, all that `randomize` does is to shuffle the local DF and print the result -- the main program never references that ordering.  At the end of your main, you simply dump the unchanged `df_shuffled` from your first sampling.

Also, you haven't concatenated the 15 shufflings; it's not clear what result you expect.  However, I can help with the function.

```
def randomize():
    df = pd.DataFrame(sales_to_do)
    df_shuffled = df.sample(frac=1)
    return df_shuffled

for i in range(15):
    df_shuffled = randomize()
    # Adapt this output to append results per your needs
    df_shuffled.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Output1.xlsx',
        index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: Hi Prune, for some reason its not working, only providing with one output

Comment: Well, what change did you make to append results instead of overwriting?  We need to see your code to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the easiest and quick way to do it is using `shuffle` from `sklearn.utils`

```
    from sklearn.utils import shuffle
    df = shuffle(df, random_state=0)
```